# Escape unicode in golang

Tags: go, unicode, escaping

I'm trying to read a file containing unicode and display it as normal string:

example.txt

processSpecification=Sp\u00e9cification du processus

materialDomain=Domaine mat\u00e9riel

Expected result:

processSpecification=Spécification du processus

materialDomain=Domaine matériel

Actual result:

processSpecification=Sp\u00e9cification du processus

materialDomain=Domaine mat\u00e9riel

I foundhow to do this in 5 min in python : 
for decodedLine in open('Z:\m1msgcatalog\PLMVocabulary_ds6w_fr.properties', 'r', encoding='unicode-escape'):
    print(decodedLine)

but I don't get how to do this in golang

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can use [`strconv.Unquote`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote)? (But be careful... that does more than just replace `\u` sequences.)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    input := `processSpecification=Sp\u00e9cification du processus`
    fmt.Println(input)
    fmt.Println(strconv.Unquote("\"" + input + "\""))
}

// Output:
// processSpecification=Sp\u00e9cification du processus
// processSpecification=Spécification du processus
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Uq4vIdNyya